# Cloudfront serve file based on cookie

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

If a user is logged into my web app (a cookie named 'token' is set), I want requests to www.myapp.com to serve an index.html from my s3 bucket for the web app.

If the user is not logged in, I'd like the index.html from my marketing site s3 bucket to be served.

Is this possible in Cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this can be done with the new [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html) CloudFront feature. I haven't actually used this feature yet, but this is the only feature I know of that would allow the sort of routing in CloudFront that you are asking about.

It [looks like](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-structure.html) you can check HTTP headers from within the Lambda@Edge function, and cookies would be sent as an HTTP header. The cookie header isn't listed in the [restricted headers section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-restrictions.html), so it should be exposed to the Lambda function. I think this will be capable of doing exactly what you want.

If you try this please let me know how well it works.

Comment: Yes... you can edit the URI (path) but the `Host:` header is read-only, so the content would need to be in the same bucket.  By forwarding and caching on this cookie (in the Cache Behavior for `/`) and rewriting the URI in the Origin Request trigger, this could be accomplished, but it would come at a cost of a reduction in the hit ratio for this page, for users who have the cookie.  But you'd have that same problem even if it were an app server (not S3) origin.  Until L@E is out of preview, it can only be associated with one distribution per AWS account.

Comment: If you wanted to actually return a 30X redirect in this case, instead of returning alternate content, you'd need to use the Origin Request trigger to actually rewrite the URI to a dummy page in the target bucket that used redirect rules to actually generate the redirect, because L@E can't change the HTTP status code, and the request headers are of course not available to response triggers.  And triggers can't alter the actual response body.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the clarification. It sounds like you've actually had an occasion to use L@E and dig into it in detail. I wonder if both the OP's S3 bucket and his website were configured as origins for the CloudFront distribution if that would make it any easier to accomplish what he wants.